# Angular 4 default selected option without ngModel

Tags: angular

I need to have the option 'Month' as default. I have seen examples where ngModel is used on a ngFor list, but it doesnt work in my case. Anybody know a solution?

Template:

```
 <select class="form-control" (change)="onAmountChanged(tippanel)" [(ngModel)]="tip.Period">
                                <option value="FourWeeks">Per 4 weken</option>
                                <option [selected]="period == 'Month'" value="Month">Per maand</option>
                                <option value="Quarter">Per kwartaal</option>
                                <option value="Year">Per jaar</option>
                            </select>
```

Component:

```
 onAmountChanged(tippanel: GeldzorgenTipGroup) {

    let total = 0;
    for (var tip of tippanel.Tips) {
        if (tip.InputValue > 0) {
            if (tip.Period)
            {
                total += this.getValuePerMonth(tip.Period, tip.InputValue);
            } else {
                total += tip.InputValue;
            }
        }
        console.log(tip.Period);
    }

    tippanel.tipTotal = total;

    this.onInputChange.emit(true);
}

getValuePerMonth(period: string, value: number): number {
    switch (period)
    {
        case "FourWeeks": return (value * 13) / 12;
        case "Quarter": return value / 3;
        case "Year": return value / 12;
        default:
        case "Month": return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question title kinda contradicts your actual question? Do you want to do it without `ngModel` or is it just "not working".

Comment: @AJT_82 I want it without `ngModel` because `ngModel` is already getting used for something else, but if there is a way I could get both working with `ngModel` then thats good too

Answer (score 2):

I solved this as follows in angular 10.

```
<select
  #selectedSort
  (change)='onInputChange(selectedSort.value)'
  class="cl-secondary">
  <option 
    *ngFor='let filter of sortFilters' 
    [disabled]="filter.value==''" 
    value="{{filter.value}}">{{filter.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and in component

```
sortFilters: any[] = [
  { name: 'Sort By', value: '' },
  { name: 'Latest', value: 'item_id' },
  { name: 'Price: Low to high', value: 'rtpAsc' },
  { name: 'Price: High to low', value: 'rtpDes' }
];
selectedSort:any;
onInputChange(e:any) {
   this.selectedSort = e;
   console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: This can be great in case you have a [formGroup] in your code and Angular doesn't allow to use with formGroup ngModel.
Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ngModel`, don't use `(change)`, use `(ngModelChange)` instead and to set a default value, don't use `value="..."` but instead assign the default value to `tip.Period` or whatever the model is you bind to `[(ngModel)]="..."` (or if you use `ngModelChange` probably better `[ngModel]="..."`

```ts
class MyComponent {
  selected:string = 'Month';

  onAmountChanged(tippanel) {
    tip.Period = tippanel;
    ...
  }
```

```ts
<select class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onAmountChanged($event)" [ngModel]="selected">
    <option value="FourWeeks">Per 4 weken</option>
    <option value="Month">Per maand</option>
    <option value="Quarter">Per kwartaal</option>
    <option value="Year">Per jaar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this, the default option works but it seems the value of the selected option doesn't get called. I've added some more code to the OP, maybe that could clarify why. Also I can't set tip.Period to tippannel since tippanel is something else.

Comment: What is `tippanel` in `onAmountChanged(tippanel)`? I have no idea what the code you added is supposed to do.

Comment: the `tippanel` in `onAmountChanged(tippanel)` is a model that gets used inside the function. So we have a model `tippanel` which has model `tips` and the `tips` model has Period. The input value inside `tip` gets added to the total value of `tippanel`. The selected period calculates the `tippanel` total for month, 4 weeks etc etc. I hope

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with [ngModel] on select.
You can not add:

```
disabled selected value=""
```

to use one option as placeholder.
The solution is to use "(change)":

```
<select (change)="selectOption($event)" >
  <option disabled selected value="">Please select:</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

and in the .ts file, get the selected value like that :

```
  selectOption(event: any) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```